# Как я могу разработать для iPhone / iPad не через XCODE и без использования компьютера под управлением OSX?

Tags: iphone, apple, ipad

Я пытался разработать приложение для iPhone, но у меня нет доступа к Mac, поэтому у меня это не сработало.
Можно ли обойти вышеуказанный блок Apple? Или, как вариант, загрузить XCODE в Windows (если это вообще возможно)?

Comment: это Эппл. Либо следуйте их правилам, либо ничего не будет. Можно конечно установить какой-нибудь хакинтош, но это все равно макось. Тут на любителя. А можно конечно пойти дальше и написать свой порт икскод на линукс/винду. Но только я сильно сомневаюсь, что оно кому то сильно будет нужно.

Comment: Еще были варианты взять Мак в аренду (физически или виртуально) .